# How to source a .csh file as well as open xilinx application in the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, source

The environment variables are written to `settings[32|64].(c)sh` at `/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS`. To launch the Xilinx tools, first source the settings script:

C-shell 64 bit environment:

```
source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.csh
```

Shell, Bash shell, Korn Shell 64 bit environment:

```
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh
```

How do I do this in the terminal?

Comment: source settings64.csh
bash: settings64.csh: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: settings64.csh: line 35: `foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )'

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking about. To source that file just use the commads that you pasted. And the location of the binary seems to be `/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ise`. I think that you can also run just `ise` command as the above scripts should add `bin` folder to the PATH.

Comment: I have a syntax error in the script; 'foreach i ( $xlnxInstLocList )'. How do I fix the script?

Comment: Probably because you're trying to source CSH script in Bash. Run the second command.

Answer (score 3):

You literally type one of those commands.

Being on Linux, your shell is Bash, so you need to source the `settings64.sh` file. You do that by typing in the command just as you yourself has typed it in the question:

```
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh
```

Since you are in a Bash shell, do not source the `settings64.csh` file. It is not for you.

Whatever software this is, it is kind enough to offer two different files, one for users of `sh`-like shells (like `bash` and `ksh`), and one for users of `csh`-like shells (like `csh` and `tcsh`).

Comment: ./settings64.sh
bash: ./settings64.sh: Permission denied

Comment: sudo ./settings64.sh

Comment: sudo: ./settings64.sh: command not found

Comment: @caleb `. ./settings64.sh` A dot, a space, and the filename.

Comment: . ./settings64.sh
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/.settings64.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/.settings64.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/PlanAhead/.settings64.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/PlanAhead
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/.settings64.sh /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE
                                                                                                                                    I get this. I'm trying to run the application. How?